Distinguish connections in MariaDB process list by custom label
I'm using JDBC to create multiple connections to a MariaDB server, and HeidiSQL to manage that database. In the "Processes" list I can see all of the connections:

But unless I happen to refresh the list while a connection is executing a specific command and I know that command, it is very difficult to distinguish the individual connections. Is there a way to get a custom text, that is specified in the Java program, into that list?
java.sql.Connection.setClientInfo("label", "Connection for purpose 1"): Does not show up in that list.
Inserting a comment at the start of every query like /*Connection for purpose 1*/ SELECT Foo FROM Bar: This would only be visible if I happen to refresh the list while a query is running, which is not useful for me.
Edit: HeidiSQL displays the "Processes" list by executing SELECT `ID`, [...], `TID` FROM `information_schema`.`PROCESSLIST`;. I do not have control over this command (unless HeidiSQL offers a way to customize it, which I don't know about). For convenience reasons (e.g. auto-refresh), I'd prefer to have this label be visible in this list, as opposed to executing a command from the editor.

see the PROCESSLIST table and look for columns which can be configured by something identifiable from client settings. I couldn't find any so i think you're smoked, unless you can customize what HeidiSQL does

@siggemannen https://cdn.memes.com/up/71458621574534061/i/1614491776540.jpg

Connection.setClientInfo sets a connection attribute, which will be temporarily (for connection lifetime) stored in the `session_connect_attrs table of the performance schema. The performance_schema is disabled by default, and needs to be activated at server start.
To list only the process for the connection with label "Connection for purpose 1" you can do that with the following SQL statement:
SELECT *, b.attr_name FROM information_schema.processlist a
JOIN performance_schema.session_connect_attrs b ON a.id=b.processlist_id
where b.attr_name="label" and b.attr_value="Connection for purpose 1"

Note: Replace the wildcard in the select with required columns from information_schema.processlist

Hm. That table stays completely empty for me. (But in any case: I added clarification to the question that I don't have control over the command that HeidiSQL executes to create the list, and that I'd rather not have to manually execute a command for this.)
